# How to find that $x^2 +y^2=z^2$ describes an infinite cone by simple algebra manipulation and change of coordinates?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am curious about how one would find that the equation $x^2+y^2=z^2$ represents an infinite cone by simple algebraic manipulations and change of coordinates (i.e cylindrical,spherical).

I've tried to work it out on spherical coordinates and I've got the following :
$$p^2\cos^2 \theta \sin ^2 \phi +p^2\sin^2 \theta \sin^2 \phi =p^2 \cos^2 \theta$$
$$\sin^2 \phi (cos^2 \theta + \sin^2 \theta )=\cos^2 \theta$$
$$\sin\phi=\pm \cos \theta $$

However I don't find really intuitive that the last equation is an infinite cone.

How do I have to interpret it ?

Comment: Are you just looking for an intuitive explanation? Can you see why $x^2  +y^2 = r^2$ is a circle with radius $r$? The cone follows from there.

Comment: Sure I do see that,but I don't see how the equation follows from that.Although I know that I should get an equation that as $z$ gets bigger describes a set of circles with growing radius ,and viceversa.

Comment: Maybe I see where the cone is.The last equation I wrote literally states that given some $\theta$ my $\phi$ is fixed so I am describing an infinite set of circles one on the other(since $\phi$ is the angle with the positive $z$ axis),which makes up a cone.Is this interpretation correct?

Comment: Yes, this is how I see it. In the original equation the radius increases as $z$ increases.

Comment: Important thing to notice is that the radius of the circle (which is obtained for a fixed value of $z$) depends linearly on the $z$- coordinate

Comment: @Tanuj Thanks for the insight .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In cylindrical coordinates, the equation becomes $r^2=z^2$.  So $r=\pm z$.

The graph of this in an $rz$-plane is two intersecting lines.  To get the graph in 3-space, we rotate about the $z$-axis (through a third dimension).  This gives us our cone.